# Rails collection_select raising errors when deployed but not under development. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm deploying a new Rails app to Heroku. This is the first time I've used Rails 3.1 with Heroku's Cedar server. I've never had so much trouble deploying an app!

First Ruby version problems, then asset precompilation errors, then gem and Procfile issues!

Now, all of the select form fields in my app appear to be generating errors. The app worked perfectly on a localhost, and I can't work out what the problem is here.

An extract from the tail:

```
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/views/gears/_panel_dataentry.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ...nd= ( collection_select (:gear, :gear_category_id, GearCateg...
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/gears/_panel_dataentry.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ..._id, GearCategory.default, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please se...
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/gears/_panel_dataentry.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ...rompt => 'Please select...' ) );@output_buffer.safe_concat('...
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:           </tr>
2011-12-08T10:35:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:           <tr>
```

This kind of error is occurring for every select field in the app.

The underlying code looks like:

```
<th><%= f.label :gear_category, "Category" %></th>
<td><%= collection_select (:gear, :gear_category_id, GearCategory.default, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select...' ) %></td>
```

Has this syntax changed in the latest version of Rails? Has anyone else encountered this issue? I'd appreciate any pointers or ideas!

Comment: what version of ruby you using locally? show us `GearCategory.default`. Try to remove spaces between `collection_slect` and `(`

Comment: I would check that all your versions are matching.  Bundler will handle the gem versions.  Are you using the same version of Ruby?  1.9.2-p290?

Comment: Thanks for both these suggestions. @Mickhail removing the spaces has worked. How frustrating, thanks for spotting this! If you post this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: hi @MikhailNikalyukin thanks for your suggestion. If you post it as an answer I can accept it

Comment: @AndyHarvey sure, glad that can help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove spaces between `collection_select` and `(`.

Comment: Simple, but effective. Thanks @MikhailNikalyukin. I deleted the space between collection_select and (, but also had to delete all spaces within the ().